# How to remove a User from a rotation of inputs?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a multiplayer Random Number Game on java.

I have already successfully built a single player version of this game but I'm struggling to figure out how I would skip over a user that guessed correctly in a Multiplayer setting.

The idea is that each user will take one turn at guessing their respective number stored in the array respective to their order.

If all the users are wrong it loops back again and asks them.

If a user is correct, when the "round" restarts it skips over the user that guessed correctly and continues to asks the remaining users.

Basically the scope of which I'm requesting you look is in the `for` loop followed by a `SysOut` saying `"Ok " + name[i] + " Please guess a number."` I hope my code is readable and any/all advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
while(run == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Random Number Game!");
            System.out.print("How many players are playing?: ");

            while(!sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print("Incorrect format, please try again! ");
                sc.next();
            }

            int numPlayers = sc.nextInt(); 

            String[] name = new String[numPlayers];
            int[] randomTarget = new int[numPlayers];
            int[] minNum = new int[numPlayers];
            int[] maxNum = new int[numPlayers];

            System.out.println("What are their names?");

            for(int i = 0; i<numPlayers; i++)
            {
                name[i] = sc.next();            
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<numPlayers; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Ok, " + name[i] + " Please select a minimum number: ");
                while(!sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    System.out.print("Incorrect format, please try again! ");
                    sc.next();
                }
                int min = sc.nextInt();
                minNum[i] = min;

                System.out.print("Ok, " + name[i] + " Please select a maximum number: ");
                while(!sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    System.out.print("Incorrect format, please try again! ");
                    sc.next();
                }
                int max = sc.nextInt();
                maxNum[i] = max;

                randomTarget[i] = (int) ranNum(min,max);
            }

            System.out.println("OK! I've picked a number for you.");

            for(int i = 0; i<numPlayers; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Ok, " + name[i] + " Please guess the number for me: ");

                while(!sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    System.out.print("Incorrect format, please try again! ");
                    sc.next();
                }

                int guess = sc.nextInt();
                int x=0;
                int counter = 0;
                int size = maxNum[i] - minNum[i] + 1;
                int[] record = new int[size];

                if(guess != randomTarget[i])
                {       
                    if(x<size)
                    {
                        record[x] = guess;
                        x++;
                    }

                    if(guess>maxNum[i] || guess<minNum[i])
                    {
                        System.out.print("ERROR: Input is not within the bounds you selected. Please try again: "); 

                    }

                    if(guess>randomTarget[i] && guess<=maxNum[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("Too high, sorry. ");
                        counter++;

                    }
                    if(guess<randomTarget[i] && guess>=minNum[i])
                    {
                        System.out.println("Too low, sorry. ");
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if(guess == randomTarget[i])
                    {
                        System.out.print("Correct!");
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Assign each user a unique name and then use set to keep the users who have guessed it correctly. Next time looping, check the set and if it contains that user then skip it! Doesn't it work???

Comment: One solution might be to use a `List` to maintain all the "active" users.  So when a user makes a correct guess, you can simply remove them from the `List`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about doing this is having an additional boolean array that is parallel to the "name" array. Start by creating a boolean array that is the same size as the "name" array:

```
boolean[] correctGuesses = new boolean[name.size];
```

If a player guesses correctly, the same index of the boolean array will be flipped to true. Before asking a player to guess, first check the corresponding index in the boolean array.

Or, consider an object-oriented approach. You could create a player class like this:

```
class Player {
    private String name;
    private boolean guessedCorrectly;

    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        guessedCorrectly = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean hasGuessedCorrectly() {
        return guessedCorrectly;
    }

    public boolean setGuessedCorrectly(boolean guessedCorrectly) {
        this.guessedCorrectly = guessedCorrectly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't think to use either option. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

For me the best to make what tou want is to use a class like failedProgrammer said.
By this way, you can first add other attributs to your player like : their scores, their names. After this you only have to use a "if" boucle to ask to each player to play or not.

Comment: I agree I'm going to try that now. Thank you!